# Tcl/tk: return vs break in a conditional statement?

Tags: loops, tcl

I'm trying to wrap my head around why my code below with a `return` inside the first conditional statement exits cleanly, but when I use a `break` I get the error `invoked "break" outside of a loop`.  Can someone explain to me, please?  My understanding was that `break` would exit the conditional, and `return` would simply return a value, exit to the body, and the Tcl interpreter would continue evaluating the code.  My desire is for code to exit if arg1 is less than arg2, and not evaluate the remaining arg3 statement.  I thought I could do this with the first code chunk.  I was surprised, however, that the second code chunk did this without then going on to evaluate arg3.

This code with the `break` gives me the aforementioned error:

```
proc myfunction {arg1 arg2} {
   if {$arg1 < $arg2} {
      puts "$arg1 too low"
      break
   } elseif {$arg1 >= $arg2} {
      puts "Cool beans!"
   }
   set arg3 [expr {$arg1 + $arg2}]
   return $arg3
}
```

This code with the `return` exits cleanly:

```
proc myfunction {arg1 arg2} {
   if {$arg1 < $arg2} {
      return [puts "$arg1 too low"]
   } elseif {$arg1 >= $arg2} {
      puts "Cool beans!"
   }
   set arg3 [expr {$arg1 + $arg2}]
   return $arg3
}
```

Comment: Where is the loop in this code sample? See the documentation for `break`: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/break.htm

Comment: And you probably want `expr` not `eval`

Comment: note that `puts` prints the string but *returns* an empty string. So `return [puts hello]` is the same as `puts hello; return ""`

Comment: Corrected typo of erroneous "eval" vs "expr".  Regarding the "where's the loop" question: exactly!  The error that Tcl spits out doesn't seem to match the code.  (I did write "loop" erroneously in my original problem statement; I've corrected that typo, too)

Comment: You can only use `break` inside a loop (for, foreach, while) -- that's what the error message is trying to tell you.

Comment: OK, that makes sense (or rather: I accept that that's how Tcl works :P) regarding `break` but why does the first `return` exit the function completely and not continue to evaluate the expression `arg3` ?  Please write this in an answer so I can upvote it (or conversely downvote my question).

Comment: I don't think there are other languages (not the mainstream ones anyway) where `break` works outside of a loop? And return works the same way pretty much everywhere too, I believe.

Comment: _"but why does the first return exit the function completely"_ - because that's precisely what it is designed to do: *return* from a function

Comment: @Jerry, the C `switch` statement needs a `break` to prevent falling through from one case to the next. Not exactly a loop, but break serves the same purpose.

Comment: Your `return [puts "error message…"]` is almost certainly not something you want to type. I'd recommend using `error "error message…"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Both `break` and `return` generate special internal exception types. They then flow out from where they were generated to something that handles them, which is (in this discussion) either a procedure hull (the thing that makes stack frames, maps actual arguments to formal parameters, and tidies up after the call) or a looping construct like `for` or `while`.

When `return` hits the procedure hull, it's converted into the normal result of the procedure, and its payload value is the result of the procedure. Loops conventionally ignore `return` and just let it flow through (technically they might do a bit of internal cleanup, especially with `foreach`, but you don't see that). There are additional options you can pass to make the `return` payload do other things, but they don't really matter here.

When `break` hits a loop, it terminates the looping. When it hits a procedure hull, it is converted into an error, which you've seen, to indicate that there is a wild `break` inside your procedure, as that's usually an indication of code being wrong.

---

The other major classes of exception handling are associated with `catch` and `try`, and the top-level handlers that deal with exceptions that go all the way.

There are two other main classes of exception: `error`, which is what all errors are and which carries additional information such as a stack trace, and `continue` which makes looping constructs go on to the next iteration.

Tcl's bytecode compiler tries to eliminate most uses of `break` and `continue` exceptions by converting them into internal jumps to the correct next stage of handling. It's not 100% successful at it, but gets close with non-crazy code or even code that is quite a bit crazy. It also eliminates the most common cases of `return`.